# Tuple indices must be integers when building a dictionary

Tags: python, tuples

I am taking an Udacity programming course and have been sitting on the same problem for a week. I finally think I am close to getting it right, but I don't get the last objection. Here is my code:

```
def process_file(f):
    # This is example of the datastructure you should return
    # Each item in the list should be a dictionary containing all the relevant data
    # Note - year, month, and the flight data should be integers
    # You should skip the rows that contain the TOTAL data for a year
    # data = [{"courier": "FL",
    #          "airport": "ATL",
    #          "year": 2012,
    #          "month": 12,
    #          "flights": {"domestic": 100,
    #                      "international": 100}
    #         },
    #         {"courier": "..."}
    # ]
    data = []
    info = {}
    info["courier"], info["airport"] = f[:6].split("-")

    with open("{}/{}".format(datadir, f), "r") as html:     
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        car = str(html)[17:19]
        airp = str(html)[20:23]
        mydict = {}
        x = 0
        table = soup.find("table", {"class": "dataTDRight"})
        rows = table.find_all('tr')

        for row in rows:
            cells = row.find_all('td')
            year = cells[0].get_text()
            year = (year.encode('ascii'))

            Month = cells[1].get_text()
            Month = (Month.encode('ascii'))
            domestic = cells[2].get_text()
            domestic = (domestic.encode('ascii'))

            international = cells[3].get_text()
            international = (international.encode('ascii'))

            if Month != "Month" and Month != "TOTAL":
                Month = int(Month)
                year = int(year)
                domestic = int(domestic.replace(',', ''))
                international = int(international.replace(',', ''))

                mydict['courier'] = car
                mydict['airport'] = airp
                mydict['year'] = year
                mydict['month'] = Month
                mydict['flights'] = (domestic, international)
                data.append(mydict.copy())
                #print type(domestic)
            #print mydict
    print data        
    return data
def test():
print "Running a simple test..."
open_zip(datadir)
files = process_all(datadir)
data = []
for f in files:
    data += process_file(f)
assert len(data) == 399
for entry in data[:3]:
    assert type(entry["year"]) == int
    assert type(entry["month"]) == int
    assert type(entry["flights"]["domestic"]) == int
    assert len(entry["airport"]) == 3
    assert len(entry["courier"]) == 2
assert data[-1]["airport"] == "ATL"
assert data[-1]["flights"] == {'international': 108289, 'domestic': 701425}

print "... success!"
```

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module>
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_elbzlfkcpw/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import studentMain
  File "/tmp/vmuser_elbzlfkcpw/studentMain.py", line 2, in <module>
    process.test()
  File "/tmp/vmuser_elbzlfkcpw/process.py", line 114, in test
    assert type(entry["flights"]["domestic"]) == int
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

I am a total beginner, I checked both the type of `domestic`, and `international`, they are both int.

Can anybody tell me where I can look up or what I did wrong?

Comment: can you post the complete traceback.

Comment: What is the *full* error message you get? The traceback tells us *where* an error occurs, not just that it occurs.

Comment: We need the full traceback, which tells us what line the error occurred on. (Once you know that, you could also add a print statement right before the error, so we can see what the offending command is)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module>
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_elbzlfkcpw/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import studentMain
  File "/tmp/vmuser_elbzlfkcpw/studentMain.py", line 2, in <module>
    process.test()
  File "/tmp/vmuser_elbzlfkcpw/process.py", line 114, in test
    assert type(entry["flights"]["domestic"]) == int
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @StephanKetterer, your traceback indicates the error does not come from the piece of code you've shown. Consider adding the relevant part in your post (edit your post) of the module `process.py`.

Comment: Isnt it a problem with this one entry in my key value pair ? the key is flights and the value is domestic and international ? sorry i am really confused as a beginner by this :(

Comment: No it's not. Sometimes, an error can be produced much later than where it actually originates. An example of this would be a SyntaxError, which can be easily produced by missing a closing parentheses on one line: the error will indicate it is coming from the 2nd line. In any case, you should post the code from the function `test` in `process.py`.

Comment: def test():
    print "Running a simple test..."
    open_zip(datadir)
    files = process_all(datadir)
    data = []
    for f in files:
        data += process_file(f)
    assert len(data) == 399
    for entry in data[:3]:
        assert type(entry["year"]) == int
        assert type(entry["month"]) == int
        assert type(entry["flights"]["domestic"]) == int
        assert len(entry["airport"]) == 3
        assert len(entry["courier"]) == 2
    assert data[-1]["airport"] == "ATL"
    assert data[-1]["flights"] == {'international': 108289, 'domestic': 701425}
    print "... success!"

Comment: @StephanKetterer, please *update* your *post*. In comments, all the formatting is lost.

Comment: I updated my post now for better formatting. I am really sorry to cause all these problems. In my defense i really tried searching other topics and the internet before i posted :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a tuple here:

```
mydict['flights'] = (domestic, international)
```

so `mydict['flights']` is a tuple. But you try to treat it as a dictionary here:

```
assert type(entry["flights"]["domestic"]) == int
```

That won't work; you'll need to use integer indices here:

```
assert type(entry["flights"][0]) == int
```

or better still, use `isinstance()` to test for types:

```
assert isinstance(entry["flights"][0], int)
```

Comment: Ok thank you all very much for your help !!!                                            mydict['flights'] = {"domestic":domestic, "international":international} helped. I did not know that in a dictionary i could have a structure like that to be quite frank. I thought i could just have key/value(s) pair.. and not something with a string describing it. Thank you all very much. i am gonna keep on learning to program :)

Comment: @StephanKetterer In reference to the bit from my answer, you can use any type that is hashable , so: strings, integers, floats, etc.  [(see hashable in this glossary)](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here you assign your data `mydict['flights']` as a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

```
def process_file(f):
    # Omitted code...
    mydict['flights'] = (domestic, international)
```

Your error then comes from an illegal access to that data type.  You are attempting to access the first item of that `tuple` by the name of variable you used in assignment:

```
assert type(entry["flights"]["domestic"]) == int
```

You either need to access your data via an integer index:

```
assert type(entry["flights"][0]) == int
```

Or you need to change your assignment to:

```
mydict['flights'] = {"domestic":domestic, "international":international}
```

[`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)s are immutable data types which are indexed by integers.  The type of access you are attempting is typical of a [`dict`ionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), where indexes can be of any type.